# How to use ipaddreses instead of container names in docker compse networking

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose for a web application that I'm creating with asp.net core, postgres and redis.  I have everything set up in compose to connect to postgres using the service name I've specified in the docker-compose.yml file.  When trying to do the same with redis, I get an exception.  After doing research it turns out this exception is a known issue and the work around is using the ip address of the the machine instead of a host name.  However I cannot figure out how to get the ipaddress of the redis service from the compose file.  Is there a way to do that?

## Edit

Here is the compose file

```
version: "3"

services:
    postgres:
      image: 'postgres:9.5'
      env_file:
        - '.env'
      volumes:
        - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
      ports:
        - '5433:5432'
    redis:
      image: 'redis:3.0-alpine'
      command: redis-server --requirepass devpassword
      volumes:
        - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'
      ports:
        - '6378:6379'
    web:
        build: .
        env_file:
          - '.env'
        ports:
          - "8000:80"
        volumes:
          - './src/edb/Controllers:/app/Controllers'
          - './src/edb/Views:/app/Views'
          - './src/edb/wwwroot:/app/wwwroot'
          - './src/edb/Lib:/app/Lib'
volumes:
  postgres:
  redis:
```

Comment: can you show us your docker-compose file?

Comment: I've added the compose file

Comment: you need to link your services and then access to them by and environment variable [more info](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)

Comment: can you provide a link of that known issue? Also a description of the exception

Comment: I found the answer to my specific qustion and posted it.

Comment: can you please provide it anyway? Curious for that issue

Comment: yep working on recreating it now

Comment: Here is a link to the issue on github https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/463 and the exception is PlatformNotSupportedException.  The workaround appears to be to use the ipaddress of the redis server

Comment: There reason I didn't provide the details of the exception and issue is because it's not docker related.  It's specifically asp.net core related.  However the prefered way to access other containers through networking is by using the name specified for the service in the docker-compose file.  I could not do this and was having trouble finding the exact ip address to use becase it was changing when I restared the containers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer.  It was something I was trying but didn't realize the address may change everytime you restart the containers.

Run `docker ps` to get a list of running contianers then copy the id of your container and run `docker inspect {container_id}` and that will output the ipaddress that you can access it with from within the other running containers.

The reason I was confused was because that address may change when the containers are started.  So I had to guess what the ip address was going to be before I started the containers.  Luckly after 5 times I guessed correctly.

Comment: You can define a network and specify an IP.  For details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address

Comment: thanks,  I'm currently resolving it with c# on start up because this is just a dev evironment.  I'm pushing it up to blumix and it has to do the same thing in production so i'm suppling environment variables and letting it get the ip based on that.